# flutter how do I use firebase_analytics with ddd architecture

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, firebase-analytics

I have an app that uses `DDD` architecture that separated the logic ( data ) from the UI ( presentation ) and `bloc` for stat management.

now I need to use `firebase_analytics` package, and I am confused now about how I should use it (best practices), should I log the events from the UI widgets ( most of the tuts doing that like `onPressed` on a button ...etc ) or log events from the `blocs` events?